# clang does not compile my code, but g++ does

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Can someone help me with this code:

```
#include <type_traits>

#include <vector>

struct nonsense { };

template <struct nonsense const* ptr, typename R>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_void<R>::value, int>::type
fo(void* const)
{
  return 0;
}

template <struct nonsense const* ptr, typename R>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_void<R>::value, int>::type
fo(void* const)
{
  return 1;
}

typedef int (*func_type)(void*);

template <std::size_t O>
void run_me()
{
  static struct nonsense data;

  typedef std::pair<char const* const, func_type> pair_type;

  std::vector<pair_type> v;

  v.push_back(pair_type{ "a", fo<&data, int> });
  v.push_back(pair_type{ "b", fo<&data, void> });
}

int main(int, char*[])
{
  run_me<2>();

  return 0;
}
```

clang-3.3 does not compile this code, but g++-4.8.1 does, which of the two compiler is right? Is something wrong with the code, as I suspect?

The error reads:

```
a.cpp:32:15: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'pair_type' (aka 'pair<const char *const, func_type>')
  v.push_back(pair_type{ "a", fo<&data, int> });
              ^        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
a.cpp:33:15: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'pair_type' (aka 'pair<const char *const, func_type>')
  v.push_back(pair_type{ "b", fo<&data, void> });
              ^        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: did you enable C++11 by -std=c++11 ?

Comment: yes, I did and also gnu++11

Comment: `func_type f1 = fo<&data, int>;` fails too.

Comment: icc 13.0.1 also compiles

Comment: I cut your code. It still [compiles](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=0ca8c2af8d807dd575bb72663cfbf486-057989889b0769918a9df63890264210) with g++ and fails with clang++. Also, if you uncomment line `auto f2 = foo<&data>;` - g++ will fails too.

Comment: edited title; clang++ compiles just fine.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No it does not.

Comment: @user1095108: Then explain how hundreds of thousands of people are using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relocating `static struct nonsense data` outside the function gets the code to compile. I'm not savvy enough to tell you why.

To customise `data` for different values of the `O` parameter, one could define `nonsense` as follows…

```
template <size_t> struct nonsense {
    static nonsense data;
    ⋮
};
```

…and use it thus…

```
template <std::size_t O, typename R>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_void<R>::value, int>::type
fo(void* const)
{
  // Use nonsense<O>::data
}

template <std::size_t O, typename R>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_void<R>::value, int>::type
fo(void* const)
{
  // Use nonsense<O>::data
}

⋮

template <std::size_t O>
void run_me()
{
  std::vector<std::pair<char const* const, func_type>> v;

  v.emplace_back("a", fo<O, int >);
  v.emplace_back("b", fo<O, void>);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I need it in the function template body.

Comment: Fair point, but now I'm wondering why you need to do this. Without understanding the purpose of the `ptr` template parameter, it's difficult to see why you have to define `fo` with respect to a static struct instead of the template parameter `O`, which provides the same degree of uniqueness.

Comment: a non-empty `struct` with members can be modified in `run_me` function template instantiations and a pointer to this modified struct can then be  used to instantiate an `fo` function template. Say, a member could be set depending on the `O` template parameter. It's a matter of convenience.

Comment: I was using the static `struct` to circumvent the `char const*` as template parameter problem. The `struct` contained a `char const*` member, that I otherwise could not use for template instantiation.

Comment: @user1095108: I've amended my answer accordingly. I hope I've understood you correctly.

Comment: Nice workaround, I suppose it compiles? But it looks like a workaround to me.

Comment: @user1095108: Isn't that what all template meta-programming is?

Comment: Well, I've asked which of the compilers was right. For now it seems the score is 2:1 in favor of `g++`, but no definite answer. AFAIK, `clang++` is right in not accepting this, but I don't know for sure.