# local variable as a non-typename argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Why is it illegal to use a local variable as a non-type argument?

For example, in the next code `local_var` cannot be argument to `X`.

```
template<int& x> struct X {};

void f(int local_var)
{
    X<local_var> x;
}
```

Comment: Template arguments are part of the *type*. What would the type of `x` be in your example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because template arguments must be evaluated at compile time, and the compiler won't know the address of a local variable until run-time (in order to bind a reference to an object, the compiler needs to know the address of that object).

Notice, that the C++11 Standard tells exactly what non-type template arguments can be provided in paragraph 14.3.2/1:

> A *template-argument* for a non-type, non-template *template-parameter* shall be one of:
>
> — for a non-type *template-parameter* of integral or enumeration type, a converted constant expression
>   (5.19) of the type of the *template-parameter*; or
>
> — the name of a non-type template-parameter; or
>
> — a constant expression (5.19) that designates the address of an object with static storage duration and
>   external or internal linkage or a function with external or internal linkage, including function templates
>   and function *template-ids* but excluding non-static class members, expressed (ignoring parentheses) as
>   & *id-expression*, except that the & may be omitted if the name refers to a function or array and shall
>   be omitted if the corresponding template-parameter is a reference; or
>
> — a constant expression that evaluates to a null pointer value (4.10); or
>
> — a constant expression that evaluates to a null member pointer value (4.11); or
>
> — a pointer to member expressed as described in 5.3.1; or
>
> — an address constant expression of type `std::nullptr_t`.

As you can see, local variables are not in this list.

Comment: Wait, but you can pass around functions as template arguments, and the compiler doesn't know the addresses of those until runtime, either.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Not sure I'm following you. Why would the address of a function be known only at run-time?

Comment: @Mehrdad: "Local" (block-scoped) variables are explicitly excluded by the third bullet point quoted by Andy, because they don't have linkage. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348611/does-static-object-in-a-template-function-have-linkage/17350254#17350254

Comment: @rici: Right, I understand the reason, I'm just saying it's not what Andy mentioned.

Comment: @Mehrdad Obviously when compiling as Position Independent Code ("PIC"), the implementation (compiler and linker, the whole suite) cannot know the address of functions or global objects until execution. It does not matter: the numerical value of the address is irrelevant here. The compiler knows that the address of a function, is, well, its address: `&::f(int)` for example, which is conceptually different from the address of any other function. The address here is not a number, it is designation. Same for addresses of global objects.

Comment: (...) OTOH, there is no such thing as the address of an automatic variable at compile time: `&local_var` does not designates *a priori* a given object; only during the **execution** of `f(int)` this expression makes sense. There is a different `&local_var` for every execution of `f(int)`.

Comment: @curiousguy: Position-independence isn't the only problem, even position-dependent code can have the same issue (see: Windows). Again,  I already understand what's happening, I'm just saying that the sentence Andy wrote wasn't the correct reason.

Comment: @Mehrdad It depends how you interpret "_to know the address of that object_": know the numerical value *or* know **the symbolic value**?

Answer (score 0):

The "value" of a template needs to be present at compile time.

```
template<int x> struct X {};
```

Even if you do not bind a reference or pass a pointer here, the compiler must know the value of the passed elements at compile time.

Replacing `int &x` with `int x` is on purpose here. Stuff about int& is answered correctly. I just wanted to point that it applies to all non-typed template arguments.

- The "value" of a reference is a reference (implementation dependent actually a pointer in most of them)

  - The address of the object must be known at compile time
- The "value" of a pointer `template<int*>` is an address...

  - ... which in turn must be known here, too, of course.
- The "value" of a value-type is the value itself which also must be known at compile time

```
X<local_var> x; // will not work, local_var does not exist at compile time
X<1> x; // works since 1 is known
```

I just wanted to (in addition to Andy's answer) prevent any conclusions that would suggest to use a value type instead of a reference.

Comment: `template<int>` is rather different from `template<int&>`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but as aschepler mentioned you’re interpreting template<int x> instead of template<int& x>

Comment: Both of you are correct and that's on purpose. I'll have a quick edit on that.